# Qt C++ BlueZ 5 QDbus Library

Tags: c++, qt, bluez, qdbus, qtbluetooth

In BlueZ 5 the DBus API has changed substantially. I previously had a working QDbus controller library for BlueZ 4 based on this: https://gitorious.org/qt-bluez-demos/

I've been googling quite a bit and cannot find any existing starting point to convert my BlueZ 4 library to BlueZ 5.

NOTE: I'm using Qt 4.8 but it seems Qt 5.0 has some QBluetooth namespace, however it has not been updated for BlueZ 5 yet either:

```
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32085?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin:activity-stream-issue-tab
```

This library is also BlueZ 4 only:

```
https://github.com/nemomobile/libbluez-qt/tree/master/bluez-qt
```

Can anybody point me to some existing code? Thanks!

Comment: Is this still unresolved one year later??

Answer (score 1):

As the corresponding [bug tracker entry](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32085) writes:

> The Bluez API has released a new major release which is incompatible to Bluez 4.x. Currently QtBluetooth supports Bluez 4.x only.

It means that, unfortunately. The bugreport is still open, and this has not been fixed yet. You will need patience or enough courage to step up and contribute to it.

Answer (score 1):

BlueZ 5 support is now in Qt [as of 5.4](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.4).  I arrived at this question because I'm creating some software for BLE devices using Qt 5.5 and I want to know how I can know if my Qt instance is in fact using BlueZ 5 or BlueZ 4.

Answer (score 1):

The KDE bluez-qt project at https://github.com/KDE/bluez-qt is a Qt-based wrapper for BlueZ 5. The API maps fairly directly to the BlueZ 5 D-Bus API, unlike the Qt Bluetooth module with its own API, so it depends on what you need.